# Can anyone find this DOJ report talking about the CIA's detention and interrogation (or torture) program?

Tags: modern, terrorism, 21st-century, torture, war-on-terror

In Ali Soufan's book[*The Black Banners - Declassified: How Torture Derailed the War on Terror after 9/11*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0864ZGNVV),on page 425a of the Kindle edition, he says:

> A July 29,2009, report by the Justice Department's Office of Professional Responsibility (OPR) stated that Boris's techniques "were not expected or intended to produce immediate results. Rather, the goal of the CIA interrogation program was to condition the detainee gradually in order to break down his resistance to interrogation."

I have tried searching parts of the quote on Google and all I get are a few hits that all lead to Soufan's book. Can anyone help me locate this report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Investigation into the Office of Legal Counsel's Memoranda Concerning
Issues Relating to the Central Intelligence Agency's Use of "Enhanced
Interrogation Techniques" on Suspected Terrorists](http://www.aclu.org/files/pdfs/natsec/opr20100219/20090729_OPR_Final_Report_with_20100719_declassifications_annotated.pdf) at p. 212.